# inline-styles for override a list item boostrap

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

Does someone know the single line for override an img in a list with my personalized img?

The line is this one that i want to change:

```
<i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i> Profile </a>
```

I try with this:

```
<i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400" style="list-style-image: url('/images/myimg.jpg');"></i> Profile
```

But it didn't work. Some help?

---

no it didn't work. 
[I want to replace the icon at left with my icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWzRj.png)

The 'complete' code is:

```
echo '<a class="dropdown-item" href="update-parameters.php">';
echo '<i class="fas fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>';
echo 'Profile';
echo '</a>';
```

the html it's printed because is verified a condition

Comment: this tag is `i` not `li`. please clear your code and send `ul` and `li` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for

```
<ul>
    <li class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400" style="list-style-image: url('/images/myimg.jpg');">Profile</li>
</ul>
```